# Errno 2: No such file or directory, but file exists

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, terminator

I have the following lines of code:

```
model_weight = "/home/Object-Detection-and-location-RealsenseD435/DNN/engine/yolov3.weights"
model_cfg = "/home/Object-Detection-and-location-RealsenseD435/DNN/engine/yolov3.cfg"
model_classname= "/home/Object-Detection-and-location-RealsenseD435/DNN/engine/classname.txt"
```

And when I try running it, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/Object-Detection-and-location-RealsenseD435/DNN/engine/classname.txt'
```

The file that's causing the error exists. I can access it via the File Application, but not through code.

Both Terminator and PyCharm give the same error messages. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Are you sure classname.txt is in that specific directory?

Comment: You only have a problem with that one file, not the others in the same folder?

Comment: Filenames are case-sensitive on Linux, make sure the case is correct.

Comment: @Barmar are they not case sensitive in all OS?

Comment: @Amolgorithm No, Windows is case-insensitive.

Comment: Yes, classname.txt is in this specific directory. Classname.txt is the only file that's causing problems. I know that what's capitalized is funky but I assure you that's how it's supposed to look

Comment: The file does **not** exist at that location. It really is that simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the other paths exist, it means that `classname.txt` may not be in the intended directory. You can try checking that through the code by doing:

```
os.listdir("/home/Object-Detection-and-location-RealsenseD435/DNN/engine/")
```

This will show you the contents of this directory, to verify if it exists and is visible at that location.

Another thing: It may be easier to not use an absolute path and instead access the the files from your current working directory.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments by Barmar, Linux file system is case-sensitive. Make sure that your file path and file name `classname.txt` is exactly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely causes:

1. File doesn't actually exist.  Just run `ls <full path to filename>` and see what you get.
2. File exists but the effective user of the script doesn't have permissions to access it.  run `sudo ls <full path to filename>` and see which user and group own the file.

Comment: If the user doesn't have access you'll get a different error.